# Kubernetes Persistent Volume Claim doesn't save the data

Tags: kubernetes

I  made a persistent volume claim on kubernetes to save mongodb data after restarting the deployment I found that data is not existed also my PVC is in bound state.

**here is my yaml file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-mongo
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: auth-mongo-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: auth-mongo-pvc
      containers:
        - name: auth-mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
              name: 'auth-mongo-port'
          volumeMounts:
            - name: auth-mongo-data
              mountPath: '/data/db'
---
# Persistent Volume Claim
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Mi
```

and I made clusterIP service for the deployment

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this whole site is based on a framework of Q&A, so for the health of the framework, can you please ask a question? You can see [ask] for guidance. Note: ['Can somebody help me?' is not really a question by our community's standards](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541)

Comment: In additional to @starball's excellent comment, please include in your question a [mcve] -- a specific set of steps that we can follow that will reproduce the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: Assuming that you are using dynamic storage provisioning using any CSI driver , because you are using a deployment kind when you destroy the deployment it destroys the related pods and furthermore depending on the reclaim policy of the default storage class which might be "delete" and hence the PVC is unbound because no pods are using it. And when you create a new deployment, new pods and new PVC is created of course empty. 
for mongo-db use statefulset kind. 

my answer has a few assumptions which is why it is in the comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if the PVC status is still `Bound` and the desired pod happens to start on another node, it will fail as the PV can't be mounted into the pod. This happens because the `reclaimPolicy: Retain` of the StorageClass (can also be set on the PV directly `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain`). In order to fix this, you have to manually overrite/delete the `claimRef` of the PV. Use `kubectl patch pv PV_NAME -p '{"spec":{"claimRef": null}}'` to do this, after doing so the PV's status should be `Available`.

In order to see if the your application writes any data to the desired path, run your application and exec into it (`kubectl -n NAMESPACE POD_NAME -it -- /bin/sh`) and check your `/data/db`. You could also create an file with some random text, restart your application and check again.

I'm fairly certain that if your PV isn't being recreated every time your application starts (which shouldn't be the case, because of `Retain`), then it's highly that your Application isn't writing to the path specified. But you could also share your `PersistentVolume` config with us, as there might be some misconfiguration there as well.